# Is it possible to pass parameters into default values of a Rust structure?

Tags: rust, structure

I have a structure which I would like to be able to pass the `..Default::default()` argument into when first initiating the structure. However, I would like the default implementation to be able to take in parameters so when I generate a vector I can use overridden defaults to generate it. Here is the code:

```rust
struct RandVec {
    vector: Vec<i64>,
    vec_len: i64,
    element_range: i64,
}

impl Default for RandVec {
    fn default() -> RandVec {
        RandVec {
            vec_len: 10000,
            element_range: 1000,
            /* The get_rand_vec() function takes in vector length and element range,
            I want to pass in vec_len and element_range so if I've declared them in
            in main() it takes those over the default values here */
            vector: get_rand_vec(/*vec_len*/, /*element range*/),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut random_vector = RandVec {
        vec_len: 10,
        ..Default::default()
    };
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4b7ff7d32069d4c2748cfcce0779ddfa), the `get_rand_vec()` function is included here.

I've looked through the documentation and I haven't found a way to do this, and I know that `default()` doesn't take in parameters, so I don't even know if it's possible to do with my approach. If there isn't a way to get default values to dynamically update what would be the recommended way to handle this?

Comment: Looks like you are looking into making a regular `new` function rather than `Default::default()` here.

Comment: Or the fancy version, a builder struct.

Comment: @mcarton thank you! That worked, I hadn't though of using `new` and I'll definitely keep it in mind for the future, would you mind posting your response as an answer so I can mark this as solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are looking into making a regular `new` function rather than using `Default::default()` here.

The `Struct { ..Default::default() }` is nothing special in Rust, the syntax is actually `Struct { ..any_expression }` and the expression cannot know about the rest of the structure, therefore there is no way to pass parameters into default values using this syntax.

Comment: May want to directly answer the titular question, as well.

Comment: I though my answer implied that the answer was "no" because there is no magic involved there.

Comment: It might imply the answer, which means that it doesn't *directly* answer it ;-). You know that people don't read thoroughly when they are looking for the quick answer.

Comment: @Shepmaster better?